# How do I get the count of records that do not have any record in the second table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Two Table

First_Table:

ID (PK), Name, Address

Second_Table:

ID (PK), InfoID (FK for ID from First_Table), BookName

I want to get the count of records that do not have any record in the second table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `not exists`.

```
select count(*) 
from first_table f
where not exists (select 1 from second_table s where s.infoid = f.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what outer joins are for (among other things):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM FIRST_TABLE t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SECOND_TABLE t2
    ON t2.INFOID = t1.ID
  WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

Because SECOND_TABLE.ID is the primary key is can't be NULL in the table, and therefore if SECOND_TABLE.ID shows up as NULL in the product of the outer join it means that no SECOND_TABLE row was found.

For future reference - I suggest that you don't use `ID` as a column name. This can be very confusing if you have 30 tables, all having `ID` as their primary key. In addition, if you use ID as the primary key name on all your tables it means that any foreign key columns must have a different name that the key column they refer to, again adding confusion. Instead, I suggest that you use `ID_` + the name of the table - thus, the primary key on FIRST_TABLE might be `ID_FIRST_TABLE` and the primary key on SECOND_TABLE might be `ID_SECOND_TABLE`. In this way every table ends up with a unique primary key column name - and if you need to have a column on, let's say, SECOND_TABLE which refers to FIRST_TABLE, the column name on SECOND_TABLE would be `ID_FIRST_TABLE`, making it immediately clear what the purpose of the column is and to which table it refers. Just a thought.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Although @vkp's answer is correct, you can also use minus to solve your problem -

```
select count(*)
from (select id from first_table
      minus
      select infoid from second_table)
```